# Using authenticate function for WHERE in Rails MongoDB throws an Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

**I created a way to generate a password using secure password with 'has_secure_password'. I was able to generate a password_digest:**

```
//this is the data in my mongo db

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4b43d55c260c07b48cbf38"),
    "username" : "admin",
    "password_digest" : "$2a$12$93GElGpXK2AcfRvhNsH23O2mPlTiV.sHLrtuesFO5HSllxDqEE796"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4b46c95c260c07b48cbf3c"),
    "username" : "jenuel",
    "password_digest" : "$2a$12$6LPYNpAzCAT/k8HHFVJT7..E0GO2iuBJolY0TPHbklz0J58/OLkRm"
}
```

**this is my model in rails**

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include ActiveModel::SecurePassword
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  field :username, type: String
  field :password_digest, type: String
  has_secure_password
  validates_confirmation_of :password
end
```

**I was able to create this users above using this function, inside my controller:**

```
def create
    if check_username(params[:username]) == false
      @user = User.new(user_params)

      if @user.save
        render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user
      else
        render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    else
      render json: { error: "Username Already Exist" }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

**And this is my login function:**

```
 def login
    user = User.where(username: params[:username])
    if user.exists? && user.authenticate(params[:password])
        render json: { message: "Logged In!" }, status: :ok
    else
      render json: { error: "unauthorized" }, status: :unauthorized
    end
  end
```

**My problem in the Login Function, when I use authenticate their is an error:**
[image]

**Please help. Is their other way to do this, to authenticate the password using Rails for MongoDB/mongoloid. Thank you So much :)**

Comment: use ` user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])` instead of ` user = User.where(username: params[:username])`.

Comment: oh thanks, it actuallly works. what is the difference of where and find_by?

Comment: As `where` return `ActiveRecord::Relation` and `find_by` return active record instance. Please refer https://medium.com/@derekfan/rails-find-by-vs-where-1c7814864e77 for more reference.

Comment: thanks @HardikUpadhyay aprecited much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the snippet shared in the post it seems like you are getting ActiveRecord::Relation as a result instead of active record object.
Refer to the line below

```
user = User.where(username: params[:username])
```

change this to

```
user = User.where(username: params[:username]).last
```

Also now changing to above mentioned code the following will not work

```
user.exists?
```

Also change the above one to the one mentioned below

```
user.present?
```

Now, you should be able to get it working.

Comment: thank you, Actually this also works thanks thanks for your answer rohan

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer of my own problem. For others who are stock in this kind of problem, you can just change this line of code.

```
user = User.where(username: params[:username])
```

to

```
user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
```

Comment: Yes find_by is a way..but is the conditions exists? working with find_by returned object?

Comment: you are checking whether the user exists or not  "user.exists? && user.authenticate(params[:password])" , will this work when you return a record using find_by ?